# Can I use the UART pin of ESP32 that also works as pins for internal flash?

Tags: arduino, esp32, nodemcu, arduino-esp32

I'm using AI-Thinker's ESP32-S board, and my use case requires all 3 UARTs present in the board.
But, from the [pin diagram](https://www.mischianti.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/ESP32-S-pinout-mischianti-high-resolution.png), I can see that the UART1 pins also work as pins for integrated flash.
Of course, I need internal flash to actually be able to use the controller, but can I use the UART pins at the same time? Is this possible?

Comment: I assume it wouldn't hurt to try. The worst that can happen is it not working.

Answer (score 0):

to use those pins without any problem you can compile the code with the flash in "dio" mode which by default does not use those pins, the spi-hd pin is to hold the memory, then the spi-wp pin is write protect. they are only used in "qio" mode that uses all 4 pins for higher communication speed, you can see the diferences here [flash modes](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32/advanced-topics/spi-flash-modes.html)